# 異なるリポジトリからインストールしたら、なぜコンフリクトしたりすることがあるのですか？

Tags: centos

異なるリポジトリからインストールしたら、なぜコンフリクトしたりすることがあるのですか？
ius と epel それぞれでプログラミング言語を開発しているわけではなく、どこかの公式から取得しているだけだと思うのですが、それでなぜコンフリクトしたりするのですか？
例えば、ius から取得したPython と epel から取得したPythonでは異なる可能性があるのですか？
ius や epel は何をやっているのですか？

Comment: コンフリクトの要因は様々であり、エラーメッセージを見てくださいとしか…。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サードパーティのリポジトリが提供するパッケージには、主に２つの役割があります。

- 公式リポジトリには無いパッケージ
- 公式リポジトリのパッケージを置き換えるもの (=より新しいバージョンを提供)

「公式には無いパッケージ」は単に追加されるだけなので問題になることは殆どありませんが、「パッケージを置き換えるもの」が注意する必要があります。

> ius や epel は何をやっているのですか？

ドキュメントの説明を読みましょう。

#### EPEL

「置き換えるものではなく」「アドオン」なのがポイントです。

> ##### [EPEL は RHEL や階層プロダクトが提供しているパッケージを置き換えるものですか？](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ/ja#EPEL_%E3%81%AF_RHEL_%E3%82%84%E9%9A%8E%E5%B1%A4%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%80%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E6%8F%90%E4%BE%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%92%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%8D%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%EF%BC%9F)
>
> いいえ、違います。EPEL はアドオンパッケージを提供するための純粋にフリーなリポジトリです。

#### IUS

IUS, REMI などは RHEL や CentOS に収録されているパッケージよりも「新しいバージョン」を提供するのがポイントです。パッケージ名は衝突しないように工夫されていますが、「OS 標準のパッケージを置き換える」場合があります。

> IUS is a yum repository that provides newer versions of select software for RHEL and CentOS.

#### REMI

> ##### [Which are the goals of this repository ?](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#goal)
>
> Providing the  latest versions of the PHP stack, full featured, and some other software, to the Fedora and Enterprise Linux (RHEL, CentOS, Oracle, Scientific Linux, ...) users.

REMI リポジトリの "remi-safe" 以外は「管理者が熟考して選択/インストールする必要があるため」デフォルトでは無効になっています。

> ##### [Why the repository isn't enabled on default ?](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#enable)
>
> The "remi-safe" repository is enabled by default, as it is really safe.
>
> Available packages in "remi" and others "remi-*" repositories override those in official repository. So their installation must be a pondered administrator choice. But it's really easy to permanently enable it.

---

#### パッケージのコンフリクト

パッケージの多くは依存する別のパッケージ (例えばライブラリ) があり、ライブラリは複数のプログラムから参照されている場合があります。

依存関係はパッケージのバージョンも重要になるので、サードパーティーのリポジトリから (OS 標準よりも新しい) パッケージを入れている場合には、依存関係のコンフリクトが発生しやすくなります。

Comment: リポジトリというのは、ざっくり言うと、依存関係を解決したパッケージの置き場所という感じですか？ やっていることは基本的には「make install」ですか？